# Python RRDtool installation issue on windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, rrdtool, rrd

Hi guys i'm new to rrdtool , i want to use rrdtool for one of my python projects, i'm trying to install rrdtool by typing this script in my command prompt

```
"python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32 "
```

this is the output that i get :

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
running build_configure
building 'rrdtoolmodule' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Irrdtool-1.4.7/src -IC:\Python2
7\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.c -o b
uild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings\python\rrdtoolmodule.o
rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.c:41:30: fatal error: ../../rrd_config.h:   No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

i have searched for a solution but had no success.
pls can anyone help !!